# Is there a function like org-agenda-date-later that only affects the scheduled timestamp?

Tags: org-agenda

I would like to be able to bulk increase or decrease the :SCHEDULED timestamps by a  number of days when in agenda view.

I only want to change the date, and retain any existing time ("hh:mm") or repeater settings for each item.

The closest solution I have found is the below bulk action. If I pass a "1" argument it will advance the timestamp to 1 day into the future. With no argument, it will change the timestamp of any marked items to today. "-1" will move the timestamp back one day.

```
(add-to-list 'org-agenda-bulk-custom-functions '(?D (lambda () (call-interactively 'org-agenda-date-later))))
```

This would be perfect except `org-agenda-date-later` does not seem to allow you to select which type of timestamp is changed. If an item has both :DEADLINE and :SCHEDULED timestamps, for example, `org-agenda-date-later` will often alter the :DEADLINE timestamp instead of the :SCHEDULED timestamp. I think it simply selects the first timestamp it finds.

Is there any way I could achieve a similar result, but only affecting the :SCHEDULED timestamps?